# theme.res Won't Open in Codename One Application

Tags: codenameone

Very weird issue I've come across. Is there anything I can do?

I have not made any changes to my computer since the last time it worked.

It seems to be an "issue" with the ResourceEditorApp, as no theme.res files are working (from other projects).

Comment: Do you get an exception, is it not working in your application or not opening in the designer tool? If the latter you can run it from command line and see the exception.

Comment: Hi. No error, just won't open. I think I might've forced quit it before. I'm going to try and reinstall the plugin. I have a feeling that'll fix it. Thanks Shai! :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the file just got corrupted for some reason. Did you look at its size? We now have new XML team support in the designer (its still experimental though) which should allow better versioning and reliability as we move along.

If the file is not 0 length and isn't working at all just send it to us and I will try to recover it.

Comment: Ah thanks that's very cool. I'm gonna try this week and let you know. Thanks again Shai!